# Accessing stream data of BackgroundAudioPlayer in WP

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to access the stream data of BackgroundAudioPlayer's AudioTrack in WP while streaming from a remote server ?

I tried something like using a Media Stream Source but that involved implementing a handler for my audio container (mp4/m4a) and I'm trying to avoid that (I need a container independent solution).

What I am looking for is to be able to process/manipulate the audio data while it's being streamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the audio stream you'll have to implement the `MediaStreamSource`.

In a per-track player your code won't be even running except when your track ends or the user hits play, pause or skip.

Comment: And even if he'll implement MediaStreamSource he'll only access the compressed audio data, without any ways to process/manipulate.